# column validation in sharepoint list formula

Tags: list, column, validation

Dears,

Hopefully someone can help with composing a formula for a validation of a column in a sp list.

I've have 3 columns with the choice "pending" or "completed". The validation would take place on the 3rd column as it never can be completed if one of the 2's status is still pending.

Hope someone could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

say you have fields f1, f2, f3  - 
F3 can be completed only if f1 AND f2 are completed. 
all three are choice fields with pending or completed as valid values. 
got to list settings - then in 'item validation' - put the following
=OR( AND(OR([@F1]="Pending", [@F2]="Pending"), [@F3]="Pending"), AND([@F1]="Complete", [@F2]="Complete", [@F3]="Complete") )
this is directly from excel (the best way to experiment with these things). 
Plreace @F1 with F1, etc. 
Note - this returns false if the two are pending and f3 is not complete but that would be easy to fix.

This returns the following (f1, f2, f3

Pending Pending Pending TRUE
Pending Complete    Pending TRUE
Complete    Pending Pending TRUE
Complete    Complete    Pending FALSE